# Take the value of the NAME field and put it in a variable,

Tags: linux, bash, csv

Through a request made to the command line, I get a response in csv format. This is the file:

```
"STACK";"STACK_ID";"NAME";"DESCRIPTION";"CREATION_TIME";"DELETION_TIME";"STATUS"
"STACK";"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:222222222222:stack/LiveStream2/00000000-6000-00e2-acd3-333333333333";"LiveStream2";"(nil)";"2013-01-23T16:01:36Z";"2013-01-23T16:22:57Z";"DELETE_COMPLETE"
"STACK";"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:444444444444:stack/LiveStream/00000000-6000-00e2-acd3-222222222222";"LiveStream";"(nil)";"2013-01-23T13:53:13Z";"2013-01-23T15:20:29Z";"DELETE_COMPLETE"
```

With a script I would like to take the value of the NAME field and put it in a variable,
Can you help me?

Comment: what do you want to do with your example output, there are 2 name values included. Use the first one, the last one or both. What about if you have more than 2 lines of data? Answer these questions as part of your question above. Good luck.

Comment: There's only one NAME value separated by semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know that NAME is the 3rd field, you have to hunt for it in the header line:

```
awk -F \; '
    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if ($i == "\"NAME\"") {
                name_field = i
                break
            }
        }
        next
    }
    { print $name_field }
' < filename
```

this outputs

```
"LiveStream2"
"LiveStream"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the example code.

```
#!/bin/sh
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=;
while read f1 f2 f3 
do
     echo "Name variable is              :$f3"

done<filename.csv
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Third field is "NAME" which is assign in variable in f3. Here varable is displayed two times.

Comment: The IFS here should be semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

Well the cut command should work well for you:
For example if your file is `test.txt`,

`cat test.txt| cut -d';' -f3` will get the field 3.

If you want to store the value line by line then use this:

```
for i in `cat test.txt`
do
  MYVAR=$(echo $i| cut -d';' -f3)
  //do something with the variable $MYVAR
done
```

NOTE: this is just one approach to your question. There are several ways to achieve what you've asked.

Answer (score 1):

Awk would be my best go at it.

```
declare NAMES=( $( cmd_that_generates_output | awk -F ';' 'NR==1{next}; { if( $3 ~ /^[^"].*[^"]$/){$3="\""$3"\""};  printf $3 " " }' ) )
```

So bash executes the comand subsititution ie everything inside the $( ) the cmd generates your csv and pipes it to awk.

Awk checks to see if the input is the first line ( NR==1 ) and moves on if it is ( {next} )

For every other line it checks that it is properly encased in quotes

```
if( $3 ~ /^[^"].*[^"]$/){$3="\""$3"\""};
```

then prints out the 3rd column seperated by the ';' ( ie the naem column ) followed by a space.

```
printf $3 " "
```

This has then expanded the $() to a space seperated list of names eg

```
declare NAMES=( name1 name2 )
```

Then the declare is executed which creates an array called NAMES with each name as a single element. so:

x.txt is the output you gave in your question.

```
pete.mccabe@jackfrog$ cat x.txt 
"STACK";"STACK_ID";"NAME";"DESCRIPTION";"CREATION_TIME";"DELETION_TIME";"STATUS"
"STACK";"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:222222222222:stack/LiveStream2/00000000-6000-00e2-acd3-333333333333";"LiveStream2";"(nil)";"2013-01-23T16:01:36Z";"2013-01-23T16:22:57Z";"DELETE_COMPLETE"
"STACK";"arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-1:444444444444:stack/LiveStream/00000000-6000-00e2-acd3-222222222222";Live Stream;"(nil)";"2013-01-23T13:53:13Z";"2013-01-23T15:20:29Z";"DELETE_COMPLETE"

pete.mccabe@jackfrog$ declare NAMES=( $( cat x.txt | awk -F ';' 'NR==1{next}; { if( $3 ~ /^[^"].*[^"]$/){$3="\""$3"\""};  printf $3 " " }' ) )

pete.mccabe@jackfrog$ echo ${NAMES[@]}
"LiveStream2" "Live Stream"
```